# How to make element with <xsl:attribute> when using <sql:query>

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, saxon

I am using saxonee-sql to connect to a database. How do I make the output xml file like this:

```
<Partners>
   <Partner type="Supplier">
          <PartnerName>name 1</PartnerName>
          <PartnerDuns>duns 1</PartnerDuns>
   </Partner>
   <Partner type="Buyer">
          <PartnerName>name 2</PartnerName>
          <PartnerDuns>dums 2</PartnerDuns>
   </Partner>
</Partners>
```

And this is the xslt:

```
 <xsl:variable name="partner"> 
     <sql:query connection="$connection" table="Partner" column="PartnerDuns,PartnerName,type" row-tag="Partner" /> 
</xsl:variable>
 <Partners>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$partner" />
</Partners>
```

The current output is

```
<Partners>
   <Partner>
          <PartnerName>name 1</PartnerName>
          <PartnerDuns>duns 1</PartnerDuns>
          <type>Supplier</type>
   </Partner>
   <Partner>
          <PartnerName>name 2</PartnerName>
          <PartnerDuns>dums 2</PartnerDuns>
          <type>Buyer</type>
   </Partner>
</Partners>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show us the result you currently get with `<Partners><xsl:copy-of select="$partner" /></Partners>`.

Comment: Now i update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can simply transform the original result with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Partner/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Partner/type">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Partner">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="type, (* except type)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then use

```
 <xsl:variable name="partner"> 
     <sql:query connection="$connection" table="Partner" column="PartnerDuns,PartnerName,type" row-tag="Partner" /> 
</xsl:variable>
 <Partners>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$partner/*" />
</Partners>
```

instead of the `copy-of`.